# warning Unexpected any. Specify a different type @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any OR Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

Tags: typescript, eslint, array.prototype.map

I have the following = code.  I am wondering if this is the appropriate use of the any.  I am getting a lint warning of  `Unexpected any. Specify a different type  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any.`

however, if I change it to string.  I get a error for map, `Property map does not exist on type string.`  The function works exactly as I want.  Is the appropriate use for ANY or is there a way to fix it?

THE CODE

```
function flatMapArr(object: Array<any>): Array<string> {
  return Object.entries(object).reduce(
    (acc: Array<string>, [k, v]) => acc.concat([k, ...v.map((s: Array<string>) => `${s} ${k}`)]),
    [],
  )
}
```

which take an array  of the form

```
{
      "arctic":[],
      "atlantic":[
             "north",
             "south",
      ],
      "indian":[],
      "pacific":[
             "north",
             "south",
      ],
      "southern":[],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export interface Oceans {
    artic:    string;
    atlantic: string[];
    indian:   string;
    pacific:  string[];
    southern: string;
}
```

You can define your object pattern as an Interface like above and use Oceans as "Type". I need more information but at first sight, Interface seems to be the solution